# Docker not routing to containers

Tags: linux, docker

Something happened to my machine and/or docker. I have purged docker and reinstalled but when I spin up a container with the default network associated with docker0 (or any network) traffic is not being routed correctly.

ip route in a working machine would show something like

```
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.0.1
```

but this is not present in my current machine. If I try to ping the container I get nothing, but can access the container if I add a route

```
sudo ip route add 172.17.0.0/16 via 172.17.0.1
```

I can't even ping the container when sourcing from the docker0 interface. Traffic is routed using my default gateway.

Relevant docker inspect

```
"Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
"IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
"IPPrefixLen": 16,
"IPv6Gateway": "",
"GlobalIPv6Address": "",
"GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
"MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02"
```

Failing ping

```
ping -I docker0 172.17.0.2
PING 172.17.0.2 (172.17.0.2) from 172.17.0.1 docker0: 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 172.17.0.2 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1020ms
```

Route Table

```
$ ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp6s0  proto static  metric 600 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp6s0  proto none  scope link  metric 600 notify 
192.168.250.0/24 dev anbox0  proto none  scope link notify
```

Interface

```
$ ip addr show docker0
75: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:76:23:4d:88 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Add route

```
$ sudo ip route add 172.17.0.0/16 via 172.17.0.1
```

Ping works

```
$ ping 172.17.0.2
PING 172.17.0.2 (172.17.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.17.0.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.090 ms
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.